# VirtualBox 5.1.34: error on Ubuntu 17.10 when I tried to start a VM

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-17.10

I tried to execute this tutorial:
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/#set-up-your-swarm

but when I execute this command

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox myvm1
```

I had this error:

> Starting "myvm1"...
>
> (myvm1) Check network to re-create if needed...
>
> (myvm1) Creating a new host-only adapter produced an error: /usr/bin/VBoxManage hostonlyif create failed:
>
> (myvm1) 0%...
>
> (myvm1) Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
>
> (myvm1) VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
>
> (myvm1) VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
>
> (myvm1) VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
>
> (myvm1) VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg*)" at line 94 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
>
> (myvm1)
>
> (myvm1) This is a known VirtualBox bug. Let's try to recover anyway...
> Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue